# Angular material textarea autocomplete

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

Do we have a textarea autocomplete component built using Angular (2 onwards)?

Experimented these below components

- http://ichord.github.io/At.js/
- https://github.com/jeff-collins/ment.io
- https://github.com/jdcrensh/angular-otobox

But those are built using jQuery and AngularJS, which is not compatible with my Angular application.

Comment: Thanks for helping me indenting the question. But I was trying to be more precise on my requirements. As people might end up suggesting me outdated angular's directives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will serve what I was looking for.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-mentions